# Debugging background.js with Chrome developer tools

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension

I've been looking for an answer to this problem and even though I've found some posts that come close, none of them proved useful to me.

The thing is, I want to debug the background.js script of a Chrome extension with real webstes. Until now, I can only debug the code loading background.html either via the address bar with chrome-extension:// or the extensions page. This is OK for some of the issues I want to observe, but I have found no way to do the same when the extension works with real sites and therefore, I can't study its behaviour in such situations.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to debug the background.js with real webstes"? When you inspect the background page via `chrome://extensions/`, you're already looking at the "real" background page.

Comment: Rob is correct. If you want to debug the output of content scripts while web pages are running, simply view the console for that site as you normally would. The background page does not provide output for code injected into a page via a content script.

Comment: I mean, when the browser loads a webpage, the extension's background.js script is runs in the background, right? And in that script there could be data structures or behaviour that depends on the visited site such as cookies. If I just load background.html and debug it as it is, there would be none of the mentioned environment conditions... or maye I am getting all the extension thing wrong?

Comment: OK, the answer I was looking for is thae following:t as the `background.js` runs obviously in the background while the user browses the web, one can debug its code keeping the debugging tool window open (debugging the background) and browsing normally in other tabs.